# How to find mean and deviation of the following samples?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

We have the following problem where
X: "Height of a plant" follows normal distribution.
$$
P(x<68) = 0.025
$$
$$
P(72<=x<=68) = 0.475  
$$
$$
P(x>72) = 0.5  
$$

How to find P(60<=x<=70)?
Do I have to find mean and deviation and then use z-table or there's something more clear?

---

Note.
If I had discrete values for example:
P(x=1) = 0.025
P(x=2) = 0.475
P(x=3) = 0.5
Then $$μ_χ=0.025*1 +0.475*2+0.5*3=2.475$$
$$σ_χ=(1-2.475)^2*0.025+(2-2.475)^2*0.475+(3-2.475)^2*0.5=0.299375$$
Then using the z-table I could calculate P(x>2.5)

How can I calculate mean and deviation for the continuous values above?

Comment: Hint: For the normal distribution, the mean is also the median. Do the values you are given give you enough information to identify the median?

Comment: median is 72 since P(x>72)=0.5. But what about the deviation

Comment: The way you want to think about this is in terms of getting the Z-score: that is, you are finding the values you need to use to transform your variable to standard normal. Can you use z-tables to find a value $a<0$ such that, for a standard normal variable, the probability that $X$ falls in the interval $[a,0]$ is equal to 0.475? Let $Y$ be the centered version of $X$, that is, $Y=X-72$. Then you know that $Y$ has the same probability of being in $[-4,0]$ as $Z$ has of being in $[a,0]$. This will tell you what you need to divide $Y$ by in order to give it the same distribution as $Z$.